# How to build complex search. EAV. FTS

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, full-text-search, entity-attribute-value

I'm building a complex search feature for a real estate listing site. To be able to search by a property category attributes I defined the model like this:

- Each **Property** has a **Category**. Categories are nested.
- Each **Category** holds a JSON specification for attributes it supports.
- Each **Property** has a list of attributes (as JSON field)

Here are the entities (keys, relationships, methods are omitted):

```
class Property(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    address_line = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(MoneyType, nullable=False)    
    attributes = db.Column(JSONB)

class Category(db.Model, BaseNestedSets):
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True, nullable=False)
    spec = db.Column(JSONB)
    override_spec = db.Column(db.BOOLEAN, default=True)
```

1. So searching by categories-attributes (without FTS) would require a user to drill down the categories tree, pick a category, provide a search input based on available textboxes, dropdowns for supported attributes.
2. We also have address, description, name which, I think, should be searched using FTS engine.
3. I know I can build a search index when creating new **Property** record with all necessary data and then use a faceted search (this requires some explanation).

How can I combine aspects **1**-**2** or **2**-**3** with mind? Can you explain the routine?